# Show loader while caching image in twig (LiipImagineBundle)

Tags: symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I use https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle to create a watermark on my images:

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('images/'~img.path~'/'~img.name)|imagine_filter('my_filter')) }}" style="display:inline-block; max-width:100%;">
```

I set a default image in my config, but to no avail:

```
# LiipImage
liip_imagine:
    default_image: '../web/assets/vendor/client/img/loader.gif'
    filter_sets:
        my_filter:
            filters:
                watermark:
                    image: '../web/assets/vendor/client/img/logo.png'
                    size: 0.1
                    position: bottomright
```

It works, but some of the images take some time to generate (I load them in an ajax modal window) so is there a way to show like a "loading gif" or similar? Currently the image is only white.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a JS lazy image load plugin